# How do I prevent a Windows service from setting its own startup type to automatic?

Tags: windows-service, startup

I have a self-starting service, but I want to start it manually instead. However, as long as the service is running, it continues to monitor its startup type status, and as soon as I change it to manual startup, it automatically changes back to auto startup.

Of course, I could stop the service and then change the start type, but when I need the service to run again, it will change itself to start automatically.

Is there any way to prevent the service from changing itself to auto-start?

Answer (score 1):

Run the service under an account that has no privilege to change services.

Comment: And hope the service handles that well.

Comment: @TomTom Of course - as we have no information about that service we can't really help with that.

Comment: I noticed that the auto-start options of some services are gray and do not allow modification, such as Scheduler. Can this be done by setting some registry key?

Comment: @埃博拉酱 Yes, mostly - but you should definitely know what you're doing in that depth.

Comment: @Zac67 So do you know which registry is to be set?

Comment: @埃博拉酱 Well, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Schedule\Start would be for the task scheduler.

Comment: @Zac67 No, this is the auto-start option, not the option to (dis)allow the auto-start option to be modified in the service center.